# FFMPEG - preview the FFMPEG command syntax before executing it

Tags: ffmpeg

Before executing the FFMPEG command line syntax, can we **preview** the command syntax, whether its is the actual we needed.

if so, pl provide a simple FFMPEG command syntax for **Crop**.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ffplay`:

```
ffplay -vf crop=iw/2:ih/2 video.mp4
```

Or `ffmpeg` (if yours supports [SDL output](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#sdl)):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf realtime,crop=iw/2:ih/2 -f sdl -
```

Or `mpv`:

```
mpv input.mp4 --vf=crop=iw/2:ih/2
```

or VLC:

*Tools* → *Effects and Filters* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) → *Video Effects* → *Crop*